# Tall man's bike - which manufacturers?

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit, tall

So, I'm 6'8".  I have a 36" inseam, and wear a dress shirt with a 37" sleeve.  I'm 220 lbs.

Is there a chart anywhere online showing bicycle geometry across brands, with data on 64cm-or-larger road frames?

1. Going to a random local bicycle shop is nigh useless. They have a strong financial interest to sell a brand they already stock, so I need some data on brands to choose the right LBS.
2. I know a custom builder can just do this, but that's not the question.

Comment: While you commented on a similar old question just now, unfortunately such questions aren't really suited for the stackexchange format: Voting to close under "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.".

Comment: That being said, your profile says you're in Pittsburgh, PA. Its a major city, so I'd expect you can find a decent bike shop to work with you on this.

Comment: I just explained, in the question, why starting with a specific bike shop... usually stinks.  :-)

In Pittsburgh, Big Bang Bikes was terrific, and helped me with my last bike.  I've since moved to Silicon Valley, where every shop has enough business that, well, I don't trust any of them yet.

Comment: And I can't imagine that the answer would obsolete quickly here.  One example is that Surly bikes tend to have longer top tubes; while a specific "this bike" will obsolete quickly, the question is "which manufacturers have geometry suitable to a tall guy with a long torso", and manufacturers don't seem to change geometry in any major way over time.  

Seem reasonable?

Comment: I suggest the same approach as for regular-size people: shop around, try multiple brands, see what works.  Clearly the labeled size is not a sufficient indicator for a man of  your stature, e.g. Giant has bikes that only go to "58 cm" yet they are just as big as a Trek "62 cm".  P.S. I like http://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-us/bikes/model/defy.advanced.1/18732/76105/ in your price range.

Comment: I'm no road bike expert but my hybrid is a GT in an "XL" frame. I'm a few inches shorter than you but not in the legs and the saddle is near the bottom of its travel. You'd want a longer stem than me probably. So they certainly cater for tall riders in some bikes. I think they're also part of a wider group of brands which might give you more scope.

Comment: @JohnZwinck; the problem is that no one ever has the XXL frame in-stock, in any model.  Of the five shops I've tried, all are very willing to order me something sight-unseen...  but no one has anything for me to try out.

Comment: @ChrisH will give GT a shot as well, thank you!  One of the worries is that just making the stem longer seems to wreck the steering; my current bike is iffy in that regard.  :-)

Comment: Certainly stem length has a major effect on handling as well as fit, both of which seem more important on road bikes. But the stem lengths seem to vary widely as standard so you might be lucky.

Comment: @DeanJ: Aha, now this is a familiar problem!  Many years ago I was helping my girlfriend find a bike.  We went to  several shops and were met with blank stares, as if a 5'1" person had never ridden a bicycle before.  She actually fit just fine on the smallest model of most bikes, but these were rarely in stock, and when they were, it was always "In a box in the basement, we'll build it if you commit to buy it."  We found literally one bike that fit her assembled but it was a pure race machine.  So we switched to Craigslist shopping, and things got much better.  You could try the same.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've been trolling craigslist for a few months.  :-)

Comment: @DeanJ I have voted to close this question in it's current form; I think deep down it's a valuable question so I encourage you edit so that it's closer to the question that Davorin Ruševljan has answered - something like "How to obtain a bike that is outside off-the-shelf size ranges". Perhaps also a post to [meta] could give you help to avoid closure.

Comment: @andy256 I think editing is the way to go as an "oversized" rider myself I would have loved to have found some articles in this vein when I was looking (and when I start looking again) for a bike. DeanJ, I'd be happy to make a pass at editing if you'd like. Oops, hangs head in shame, just noticed that this is not a new question…

Comment: No worries at all!  See my own answer to the question below, which was damn awesome.

Comment: I've massively rewritten the question; can folks who closed it vote to reopen, if you see this?

Comment: I think it will be automatically queued for review.

Answer (score 2):

Found this chart, of various models of bike stack height vs reach; this pretty much tells me what I should go look for, and which manufacturers - if any - have a probable fit.

http://cyclingabout.com/list-of-xxl-xxxl-bikes-for-tall-cyclists-62-63-64cm/

Answer (score 1):

You may consider contracting some custom frame builder, if you shop around you could get custom frame set in range of $2k maybe less, which would leave you $1k for rest of the bike . A quick google search showed some builders even locally in Pittsbourgh, although it is often not necessary that they are located in the same town.

Comment: Just updated my profile; I'm in Mountain View, CA now.

Would a custom frame in the $2k range be good/great/terrific/acceptable/bad?  I don't really have a feel for it, honestly.

Comment: I do not own one, and it can vary from builder to builder, but I would expect it to be of better quality than any mass produced one. And it would be built to your proportions.

Comment: I thought about custom also, and while it can be done for $3K total, it won't be very light.  Almost certainly it will be steel, not super-high end of course, and perhaps not as stiff as what's being mass produced these days.  It's worth considering, but it will be quite a different bike than a typical modern "road bike."

Comment: @JohnZwinck What's the bottom-end of a custom cost to compete with a stock road bike that cost $2500 new, today?

Comment: @DeanJ: It depends what you mean by "compete."  In flat-ground speed (aero)?  In climbing speed (weight)?  In looks?  In durability?  In credit-card touring?  In resale value?  I don't mean to be difficult, I'm honestly not sure what your priorities are beyond "road bike"...and I think *on average* that people who buy pure road bikes tend to value things that are easily found on mass-produced bikes (perhaps because that's what the marketing people want us to do!).

Comment: If you're in Mountain View why don't you check out [Rivendell](http://rivbike.com). Their bikes are semi-custom and they can fit reasonably big people (I'm 6'4" and have been lusting after one of their bikes for a while now).

Comment: For those who are excessively ground challenged, [DirtySixer](http://dirtysixer.com) makes some of the tallest bikes around.